# Map task got stuck and never completes

Tags: hadoop

Hi i am running a Hadoop Job. Always my 66th Map Task is failing due to timeout after completing 16.24% and getting stuck there.

For the default timeout of 5 mins i am getting error: ****Task attempt_201403131358_0001_m_000066_0 failed to report status for 1802 seconds**. Killing!**. So I increased the mapred.task.timout to 0(infinite time) expecting 5 mins of default timeout is not good enough for the task to finish. But now my job never ends and map task is still stuck at 16.24% only.

Could any one please help me what this problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you do in the mapper?

Comment: Mapper just extracts some fields from input using regex and sends it to reducer. Do you think Mapper task can stuck due to some problem in code ?. Because Task i googled for "attempt_201403131358_0001_m_000066_0 failed to report status for 1802 seconds. Killing!" error and all the answers say it is a problem related to Memory Consumption

Comment: It maybe because the mapper is too slow to process the data. Is it your regex too complicated or your input is too big? In addition, do you store any intermediate data in the mapper which can be very large?

Comment: As i said i increased task timeout to 30 mins and infinite time from the default setting of 10 mins(600000) in mapred-site.xml and in both cases the task still got stuck at 16.24% for 30 mins and forever respectively. The task number is 66. Out of my 192 tasks for the job i don't know why only task 66 has problem in completing.

Comment: Can you check if there is any infinite loop in your code?

Comment: No I am sure there is no such infinite loop. It is just an if-else if-else logic for each line the mapper executes so the task can never go to infinite loop.

Comment: DId this got resolved?